# How does I18n set locale if http header support multiple languages

Tags: ruby, rails-i18n

if accept_language in http header is simple and straightforward like:

`'en'` or `'en-us'`, Setting I18n's locale is easy, just like:

```
I18n.locale = request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']
```

But what if the http header is complicated like:

```
Accept-Language: fr-CH, fr;q=0.9, en;q=0.8, de;q=0.7, *;q=0.5
```

How to set I18n's locales now???

Thanks.

Comment: You might start by looking at the [specifications here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Language)

Answer (score 1):

Why reinvent the wheel? :D [`http_accept_language`](https://github.com/iain/http_accept_language) gem does it super-easy (and even works as a Rack middleware).

Comment: looks cool but hasn't been maintained much it seems in the last 2+ years, but I did expect there was a gem for this, didn't bother to look.

Answer (score 0):

In the example you've provided, the languages are already sorted so it should be pretty easy to determine which locale to use based on that. I wouldn't expect them to be sorted other than high to low.

```
header = 'fr-CH, fr;q=0.9, en;q=0.8, de;q=0.7, *;q=0.5'
langs = header.scan(/([a-z]{2};q=\d.\d)/).flatten
langs.sort_by!{|l| l.split('=').last.to_f}.reverse! # insure sorted by weight may not need this.
available_locals = I18n.available_locales.select{|locale| langs.any?{|l| l.match(locale.to_s)}}
#[;en, :fr, :de] for example

use_language = langs.find{|l| available_locals.include?(l[0..1])}.try(:first, 2)
```

Now if `use_locale` is nil, you'll need to fallback to something.  If you read the specifications on the purpose of the header, there are likely better ways of getting the preferred language of your users.

Answer (score 0):

The library from the accepted answer seems simple enough to use even though it hasn't been updated in years, however, I found [this one](https://github.com/cyril/accept_language.rb) which is even simpler, but looks more healthy (thanks to [ruby-toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/projects/accept_language)).